# Diagram symbol I've never seen

Tags: diagram, symbol

So my buddy brought me his Kawasaki Ninja service manual and asked me what this symbol is - sort of looks like part of a diode with a box instead of a line and is half shaded. I've tried looking it up but haven't had any luck and in the context of the diagram not a ton of things make sense. My best guess is they're connectors?

Also in the legend BK is black, Y is yellow and G is green.

Anybody know what these are?

[image: Strange symbol]

Comment: What is the full context of these symbols?  All I can see is Rear Left, Turn Signal, Light.  License Light.  I'm guessing these are some kinds of lights by that slim context

Comment: I think the lights are represented by the bulb symbol, though, not the diode+box symbol.

Comment: I'd guess it's actually the symbol for the type of connector used on the wire to the light. The one above it I'd guess is connected with a 2-pin block connector and perhaps the ones in question are individual, maybe bullet type. Usually manuals have a key to symbols.

Comment: @Funkyguy You are right, it is the turn signal electrical diagram. Nothing unusual there.

Comment: @Funkyguy That looks like cuneiform script to me. LoL

Comment: I too guess these are symbols for the connectors.

Comment: OH WHOOPS! I was looking at the bulbs, not the diode things.  It is clearly a monday

Comment: Considering that there are wires on the left and a light bulb on the right, it is almost certainly a connector.  Especially note that the color of one of the wires changes from G (green) on the left to GY (green/yellow) on the right.

Comment: @JohnU I forgot to mention that I scoured the electrical section of the manual and it has no legend for that symbol :(

Comment: What lovely fullwidth Romaji that is...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Searching the web for information on motorcycle electrical schematic symbols shows that the symbol in question is a connector. The left side (the box) indicates the female side while the right side (the arrow shape) is the male side.

Comment: Can you provide an example of such a site?

Comment: Look at: http://www.ktm950.info/how/Electrical%20Shop/Wiring/Basics/Basic_wiring.html

Comment: You get a point for finding that symbol somewhere but as a rule I generally don't trust sites with Comic Sans font (I was actually on that site during my research but dismissed it). Either way I'm getting more confident this is a connector symbol. I'll go and take a look at his actual bike soon to confirm. Thanks for finding that.

Comment: (OT) 'Don't let the comic sans throw you' - [classic quote](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/72559/best-way-to-test-a-high-current-pcb-design-70a-12v) linking to [an excellent electronics article.](http://www.mcmanis.com/chuck/robotics/projects/esc2/FET-power.html)

Comment: That hurt my eyes and brain.

Answer (score 1):

That symbol is an old standard of representing a connector (those plastic connectors very similar to the connecters of ide cables of hard drives).