# Need help identifying a strange symbol in a wiring diagram

Tags: diodes, wiring, diagram, symbol

I have this simple wiring diagram for an old tractor, and there are some symbols that look almost like diodes, but not quite. I have highlighted most of them in red in the attached image. Do these symbols represent diodes, or something else?

The text in the wiring diagram is in Norwegian, but do the following substitutions, and you'll understand most of it:

- lys is light
- bryter is switch
- hoved is main

[image: Circuit diagram]

Comment: Here's an [old question that's essentially a duplicate](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/124809/7036).  But, since it's picture-based, it was near-impossible for the O.P. to find that one.  BTW, FYI, there is a specialized stack dedicated to vehicle maintenance and repair http://mechanics.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 4):

I expect that those symbols represent connectors, since they seem to (mostly) be between a light or other device and the wiring harness.

Comment: Do you think that the little triangle represents a male pin and the little rectangle represents a female pin?

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense. :) I did quite a bit of googling for for wiring diagram symbol lists, and none of them had these symbols. I guess they just invented something new for this one.

Comment: @NickAlexeev: no, it looks to me like the arrow represents the male side of the connector.  The arrow is on the load side of the connection, and the box (female) is is on the source side.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it represents, when you have just one or two by themselves, crimp "bullet" connectors, like these:

[image]

When you have a lot together it may represent larger multi-way connectors, such as these:

[image]

Comment: Given that the Original Poster mentioned that this is an old tractor, I highly suspect that all of the connectors are of the "bullet" type.  That was the most common connector that I used to see when I was a kid and fooling around with the electrics on old vehicles and farm equipment.

Comment: And, yes: the triangle would represent the male pin that is exposed when unplugged; the rectangle would represent the rubber-insulated female socket.